# Deploy third party authentication secret file for Net Core mvc app to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, credentials

I created a .net core identity application, supporting google login and is working on local.
As for the Google OAuth credential, I am using secret manager toot, which create a secret.json in

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\<user_secrets_id>\secrets.json
```

Now I am trying to deploy the application to AWS .NET (Window/IIS) platform using the visual studio aws toolkit.
While as the secret file is not deployed, the application cannot retrieve the google's credential hence the application cannot be started.

How should I deploy or put me secret file to my server?

secret.json

```
{
  ...
  "Authentication:Google:ClientId": "my client ID",
  "Authentication:Google:ClientSecret": "my client password"
}
```

startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{      
    ...
    services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: How are you using secret manager tool in your code?

Comment: In Visual studio, I am just right clicking my solution and click "manager user secrets ". It will directly open the secret.json for me to insert my credential. And I think the Core Identity will take the credential in file by itself. As I did not set any file path for the sercet.json anywhere.

Comment: You can read detailed article [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/05/user-secrets-in-a-net-core-web-app.html) with an example of Twilio Credentails.